# Vuejs content in double quotes not visible while loading

Tags: vue.js

On the following snippet, the `"Android"` will be visible **after** page loads (I guess when js loads).

At first, the page displays up-to the first quote, namely: `Try` . Then it will load the whole placeholder correctly: `Try "Android"`

Is it possible to display the content inside the double quotes also while page is loading?

```
<template lang="pug">
input( placeholder='Try "Android"' )
</template>
```

Comment: That's encapsulated in a Vue Component, right? How are you using this component? I mean, it will be shown only when you load the component and shows it (when the browser finished downloading the javascript, etc)... Can you be more clear on what exactly you want?

Comment: Yeah this is Component and used directly. Well the thing is that it isn't visible when the component is shown. At first, the page displays up-to the first quote, namely: `Try `. Then it will load the whole placeholder correctly: `Try "Android"`. Question is can this be avoided?

Comment: This does not make sense to me... I mean, there is no reason to render only the `Try` and then the rest... Could you share the code of how you are using the component? Maybe even reproduce it in a fiddle?

Comment: Also, I don't know if this may be a `pug` related thing, but have you tried escaping the quotes like I did here?: https://jsfiddle.net/tyqh7qkt/

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. `Try "Android"` always appears fully to me.